# How to delegate() HTML Elements in a bootstrap popover, using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I m trying to enable, disabled controls by clicking edit button but I could not access it using jQuery delegate function.Here is code:

```
$('#table-view-task').delegate('tr:not(:first)','click', function(){
    var id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    var task = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        delay: { show: 0, hide: 0 },
        title: function () {
                return '<div>'+task+'</div>';
        },
        content: function () {
                return  '<div id="pop-container">'+
                        '<label>ID</label>'+
                        '<input type="text" value="'+id+'" id="txt-edit-id" disabled/>'+
                        '<label>Task</label>'+
                        '<input type="text" value="'+task+'" id="txt-edit-task" disabled/>'+
                        '<a href="#" class="btn" id="btn-edit-task">Edit</a>'+
                        '<a href="#" class="btn" id="btn-save-task">Save</a>'+
                        '</div>';
        }
    });  
});
```

This prints popover properly with all html elements.How to access those elements with jquery.
So how to access edit link.Here is how I m trying to do that:

```
$('#pop-container').delegate('a','click', function(){
    alert('editing');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cancel the default action for the links [EDIT: and listen to `body` instead of `#pop-container`]. Try

```
$('body').delegate('#btn-edit-task, #btn-save-task','click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('editing');
});
```

If you don't cancel the default action for the links, they'll just take you to the URLs specified by their `href` attributes.

Note that since `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method for jQuery 1.7 and higher, it would be even better to do:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn-edit-task, #btn-save-task', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('editing');
});
```

Comment: still not working.I even used id as selector.Its not working in other elements like input.

Comment: Sorry, that jumped out at me, but I just noticed something even more important -- the popover isn't getting appended to that table, it's getting appended to the body of your document. So you need to delegate the event handler to `body`, not the table. I'll edit my answer now.